# sorting points: concave polygon

Tags: c++, geometry

I have a set of points that I'm trying to sort in ccw order or cw order from their angle.  I want the points to be sorted in a way that they could form a polygon with no splits in its region or intersections.  This is difficult because in most cases, it would be a concave polygon.

```
point centroid;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  // I read a set of points into a struct point array: points[n]

  // Find centroid
  double sx = 0; double sy = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    sx += points[i].x;
    sy += points[i].y;
  }
  centroid.x = sx/n;
  centroid.y = sy/n;

  // sort points using in polar order using centroid as reference
  std::qsort(&points, n, sizeof(point), polarOrder);
}

// -1 ccw, 1 cw, 0 collinear
int orientation(point a, point b, point c)
{
   double area2 = (b.x-a.x)*(c.y-a.y) - (b.y-a.y)*(c.x-a.x);
   if      (area2 < 0) return -1;
   else if (area2 > 0) return +1;
   else                return  0;
}

// compare other points relative to polar angle they make with this point
// (where the polar angle is between 0 and 2pi)
int polarOrder(const void *vp1, const void *vp2)
{
  point *p1 = (point *)vp1;
  point *p2 = (point *)vp2;

  // translation
  double dx1 = p1->x - centroid.x;
  double dy1 = p1->y - centroid.y;

  double dx2 = p2->x - centroid.x;
  double dy2 = p2->y - centroid.y;

  if      (dy1 >= 0 && dy2 < 0) { return -1; }  // p1 above and p2 below
  else if (dy2 >= 0 && dy1 < 0) { return  1; }  // p1 below and p2 above
  else if (dy1 == 0 && dy2 ==0) {               // 3-collinear and horizontal
      if      (dx1 >= 0 && dx2 < 0) { return -1; }
      else if (dx2 >= 0 && dx1 < 0) { return  1; }
      else                          { return  0; }
  }
  else return -orientation(centroid,*p1,*p2);   // both above or below
}
```

It looks like the points are sorted accurately(pink) until they "cave" in, in which case the algorithm skips over these points then continues..  Can anyone point me into the right direction to sort the points so that they form the polygon I'm looking for?
Raw Point Plot - Blue, Pink Points - Sorted
[image]

Point List: http://pastebin.com/N0Wdn2sm   (You can ignore the 3rd component, since all these points lie on the same plane.)

Comment: As you use C++, you may use `std::sort` instead of `std::qsort`.

Comment: @DashControl `std::sort` doesn't require `vector`, but using `vector` is also a good idea compared to array.

Comment: What is that `centroid` in `polarOrder`? Where is it declared? Where and how is it initialized?

Comment: It's a global variable that I did not include in the snippet

Comment: @DashControl: Great, but where do you initialize it with the actual values? In your code you initialize the local `centroid`, which is later not used at all. Why?

Comment: I set the values right before I call the sort

Comment: @DashControl: "Right before the sort" you set the values in the *local* variable, as I said above. You never set the global one.

Comment: Why is there three bits of data per line in the point list?

Comment: The points all lie on the same z-plane.  the 3rd bit is the z-coord, which is the same every line.

Comment: Can you explain the image in your question? Pink vs blue? Its it the raw data or the results or both?

Comment: Both. The pink are the sorted points. Blue is the raw that has not been visited by the sorting algorithm.    I have updated the image in question.  I hope it is more clear.

Comment: @DashControl, how do you know they have disappeared? they can be ordered wrongly for some reason, if you take one of the "missing" points and see where it is in the ordering what do you get?

Comment: @Surt. Thanks for your comment.  I don't recall ever saying the points had disappeared, they are simply ordered in a fashion that is incorrect to my specifications.

Comment: @DashControl, the incorrectly ordered points are they all left and below centroid and right and above start point?

Comment: In this example, yes.  But in other cases, that's not necessarily the criteria for the unordered points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below (sorry it's C rather than C++) sorts correctly as you wish with `atan2`.

The problem with your code may be that it attempts to use the included angle between the two vectors being compared.  This is doomed to fail.  The array is not circular.  It has a first and a final element.  With respect to the centroid, sorting an array requires a total polar order: a range of angles such that each point corresponds to a unique angle regardless of the other point.  The angles are the total polar order, and comparing them as scalars provides the sort comparison function.

In this manner, the algorithm you proposed is guaranteed to produce a star-shaped polyline.  It may oscillate wildly between different radii (...which your data do! Is this what you meant by "caved in"?  If so, it's a feature of your algorithm and data, not an implementation error), and points corresponding to exactly the same angle might produce edges that coincide (lie directly on top of each other), but the edges won't cross.

I believe that your choice of centroid as the polar origin is sufficient to guarantee that connecting the ends of the polyline generated as above will produce a full [star-shaped polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-shaped_polygon), however, I don't have a proof.

**Result plotted with Excel**

Note you can guess from the nearly radial edges where the centroid is!  This is the "star shape" I referred to above.

[image]

To illustrate this is really a star-shaped polygon, here is a zoom in to the confusing lower left corner:

[image]

If you want a polygon that is "nicer" in some sense, you will need a fancier (probably *much* fancier) algorithm, e.g. the Delaunay triangulation-based ones others have referred to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct point {
  double x, y;
};

void print(FILE *f, struct point *p) {
  fprintf(f, "%f,%f\n", p->x, p->y);
}

// Return polar angle of p with respect to origin o
double to_angle(const struct point *p, const struct point *o) {
  return atan2(p->y - o->y, p->x - o->x);
}

void find_centroid(struct point *c, struct point *pts, int n_pts) {
  double x = 0, y = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n_pts; i++) {
    x += pts[i].x;
    y += pts[i].y;
  }
  c->x = x / n_pts;
  c->y = y / n_pts;
}

static struct point centroid[1];

int by_polar_angle(const void *va, const void *vb) {
  double theta_a = to_angle(va, centroid);
  double theta_b = to_angle(vb, centroid);
  return theta_a < theta_b ? -1 : theta_a > theta_b ? 1 : 0;
}

void sort_by_polar_angle(struct point *pts, int n_pts) {
  find_centroid(centroid, pts, n_pts);
  qsort(pts, n_pts, sizeof pts[0], by_polar_angle);
}

int main(void) {
  FILE *f = fopen("data.txt", "r");
  if (!f) return 1;
  struct point pts[10000];
  int n_pts, n_read;
  for (n_pts = 0; 
       (n_read = fscanf(f, "%lf%lf%*f", &pts[n_pts].x, &pts[n_pts].y)) != EOF;
       ++n_pts)
    if (n_read != 2) return 2;
  fclose(f);
  sort_by_polar_angle(pts, n_pts);
  for (int i = 0; i < n_pts; i++)
    print(stdout, pts + i);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is good. I have also found a method that could form the polygon I'm looking for by fitting a spline through various points within your polygon. As a result, you end up with connected line segments instead of points, and the segments ended up being easier to sort. Thank you @Gene.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first and foremost, I see `centroid` declared as a local variable in `main`. Yet inside `polarOrder` you are also accessing some `centroid` variable.

Judging by the code you posted, that second `centroid` is a file-scope variable that you never initialized to any specific value. Hence the meaningless results from your comparison function.

The second strange detail in your code is that you do `return -orientation(centroid,*p1,*p2)` if both points are above or below. Since `orientation` returns `-1` for CCW and `+1` for CW, it should be just `return orientation(centroid,*p1,*p2)`. Why did you feel the need to negate the result of `orientation`?

Comment: I see.  Thank you.  So a fix would be to set the global centroid through a function like `void setCentroid(double &sx, double &sy)` and assign the values that way?

Comment: @DashControl: Well, if you insist on using the C function `qsort`, then you have no other choice but to pass `centroid` as a global variable (since there's no other way to pass additional context to `qsort`). You will have to set that global variable to proper value before calling `qsort`. How you set it - doesn't matter. You can create a function for that. Or you can set it directly, just like you do it already in `main` (just remove the local declaration of `centroid` in `main` and you are done).

Comment: Many platforms offer a non-stanadard version of `qsort` (`qsort_s` or `qsort_r`), which would allow you to implement the same thing without a global variable. These functions accept an extra "context" parameter. You might want to look into that. However, since you are using C++ a better idea would be to abandon `qsort` entirely and use a C++ function `std::sort`. It is possible to pass context to `std::sort` without introducing a global variable. (But you'll have to learn to use functors for comparison).

Comment: I made the change but I'm still receiving a similar result for that left most edge.  I'm wondering if this could be an numerical issue since the points so close together..

Comment: @DashControl: Maybe. So, where exactly is the `centroid` located in your picture? I don't see it marked in your picture. And I still don't understand what's that `-` doing in `return -orientation(centroid,*p1,*p2)`.

Comment: I added a new picture with the `centroid` plotted.  The `-orientation` is supposed to force the dominate orientation to stay clockwise.

Comment: @DashControl: Clockwise??? But your comparison function seems to be written for counter-clockwise ordering. OK, first things first: according to your convention, which way is your Y axis pointing? Up or down?

Comment: @DashControl: That's what I assumed originally. But if Y is pointing up, then those `if`s in your `polarOrder` perform *counter-clockwise* ordering in `[0, 2pi)` range. The very first `if` says that "above" point is smaller than "below" point. That's *counter-clockwise* ordering. So, again, what are you trying to do? Clockwise or counter-clockwise?

Comment: Well, either or but I was trying to stay oriented clockwise.  I think I may have changed those `ifs` when I was trying to make the sorting work.  But would that explain why it's still skipping points?

Comment: @DashControl: If your comparison function is *inconsistent* (in CW vs. CCW sense), then it will violate some abstract ordering requirements imposed by `qsort`, e.g. it won't be *transitive*. Such inconsistent comparison function triggers undefined behavior in `qsort`. It might lose data or cause a crash in `qsort`.

Comment: Okay, So I inverted the `ifs` to mach a clockwise sort.  I also changed `-orientation` to `orientation`.  Still getting the receiving the same points being skipped.

Comment: @DashControl: No, you have to do only *one* of those things, not both. If you want CW sort, you have to invert your `if`s, but keep `-orientation`. If you want CCW sort, you have to keep the `if`s as is, but change `-orientation` to `orientation`. If you do both, you will end up with an inconsistent comparison again.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that as I was re-reading your comments.  I edited my code to reflect the suggested changes.  Still having issues there.

Comment: @DashControl: It would be nice to see what version of the code we are talking about now, since I kinda lost track of what you changed and what you kept as is.

Comment: The code hasn't changed much.  I've updated it to the latest version.  But now I'm exploring how to sort points that form a concave shape and not a convex.  If you look at the image, the program is screwing up where the points cave in.  I'm assuming that is the issue.

Comment: Also added a link to the point list, if anyone wants to give the sort a go.

Comment: @DashControl: What exactly does "skips points" mean? You have an array of size `n` on input, you have an array of size `n` on output. So, assuming the comparison function is valid, points can't just disappear. They can only get rearranged. Are you simply unhappy with the final ordering? Or is there something else? Note, BTW, that polar angle ordering will not produce a "nice" continuous shape in your example, because it has concave areas.

Comment: Exactly, I want something that produces a continuous shape that will allow to connect the sorted points as line segments with no split through the region itself.

Comment: @DashControl: Well, this is a rather popular area of computational geometry. If you want to obtain a continuous shape by *polar angle ordering* your polygon and your polar center must satisfy one important property: the whole interior of the polygon has to be visible (observable) from the polar center. (A popular analogy is: if your polygon is a museum room, then a security camera installed in the polar center must be able to monitor the whole room.) If your polygon and center do not satisfy that property, then the polar angle ordering will not produce the original polygon.

Comment: What you have in your picture definitely does not satisfy that property. The concave portion of the polygon boundary on the bottom left makes is "unobservable" from your center point. For this reason polar angle ordering will not produce your polygon. It just doesn't do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your original points don't appear form a convex polygon, so simply ordering them by angle around a fixed centroid will not necessarily result in a clean polygon. This is a non-trivial problem, you may want to research [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) and/or [gift wrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) algorithms, although both would have to be modified because your polygon is concave. The answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/24589) is an interesting example of a modified gift wrapping algorithm for concave polygons. There is also a C++ library called [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/hull_2d.php) that may do what you need.

But...if you really do want to do a polar sort, your sorting functions seem more complex than necessary. I would sort using [atan2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan2/) first, then optimize it later once you get the result you want if necessary. Here is an example using lambda functions:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    struct point
    {
        double x;
        double y;
    };

    std::vector< point > points;
    point centroid;

    // fill in your data...

    auto sort_predicate = [&centroid] (const point& a, const point& b) -> bool {
        return atan2 (a.x - centroid.x, a.y - centroid.y) <
                atan2 (b.x - centroid.x, b.y - centroid.y);
    };

    std::sort (points.begin(), points.end(), sort_predicate);
}
```

Comment: I tried that method but my points were not in sorted order.  I still had trouble with the points that "caved" in.  If you could achieve the desired result with `atan2`, then I will accept your solution.  I have included the point list for testing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "caved in"...file sharing networks are blocked where I am so I can't access your data, sorry.